# Multiple Regression in R: effect of covariable on factor or the contrary?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

I understand that this might a very simple question for people with a background in statistics. And yet, I can't find a clear answer suited to my (not so) particular case :(

I have a regression model with two categorical predictors (A, with two levels A1 and A2 and B, with two levels B1 and B2), and a numeric predictor Z.

I'm interested in the interaction between Z and B, but specifically in one level of A (A1, my reference level).

As such, I fitted the following model:

```
lm(Y ~ A/B*Z, data=df)
```

This returns me the following:

```
Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   -0.80420    0.02185 3160.00000 -36.811  < 2e-16 ***
A2             1.55943    0.02968 3160.00000  52.541  < 2e-16 ***
Z              0.07688    0.02561 3160.00000   3.002 0.002706 ** 
A1:B2          0.12481    0.03413 3160.00000   3.657 0.000259 ***
A2:B2         -0.09231    0.03500 3160.00000  -2.637 0.008397 ** 
A2:Z           0.05906    0.03072 3160.00000   1.923 0.054590 .  
A1:B2:Z       -0.06872    0.03959 3160.00000  -1.736 0.042668 *  
A2:B2:Z        0.01222    0.03385 3160.00000   0.361 0.718208
```

I believe that the 3 lines of particular interest, for me, are:

```
Z              0.07688    0.02561 3160.00000   3.002 0.002706 ** 
A1:B2          0.12481    0.03413 3160.00000   3.657 0.000259 ***
A1:B2:Z       -0.06872    0.03959 3160.00000  -1.736 0.042668 *
```

As far as I understood, the first line represents the linear relationship between my outcome Y and the linear predictor Z, in my reference level A1B1 (*and that this is not a "main effect"*). Thus, we can say that there is a positive linear relationship between these two.

Also, going from A1B1 to A1B2 (the second line) results in a significant increase of Y.

The third line cristalizes my issue. Does it say that:

1. For each increase of Z, the effect of "B2" (the second line)
   decreases (and is approx. `0.12-0.06=0.6`)?
2. Or that whithin B2, the effect of Z (the first line) is
   significantly smaller (and is approx. `0.07-0.06=0.1`)?

What is even more confusing for me is that if I swap those variables in the formula, the result is identical:

```
lm(Y ~ A/Z*B, data=df)

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
...
B2             0.12481    0.03413 3160.00000   3.657 0.000259 ***
A1:Z           0.07688    0.02561 3160.00000   3.002 0.002706 ** 
...
A1:Z:B2       -0.06872    0.03959 3160.00000  -1.736 0.082668 .  
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if I understand well your question, you should interpret the line A1:B2:Z of your results as: when `A==A1` and `B==B1`, then an increase of `Z` of 1 make Y be reduce by 0.06872.

It's important to understand that this reduction is added to the effect of `Z`alone (0.07688).  The interaction `A2:Z` (-0.09231) isn't important in that case as `A!=A1`.  Because of the interaction, the effect of `Z` is changing depending of the value taken my your variable `A` and `B`.

What you have here is a linear model like that:

```
Y = int + A2 + Z + A1:B2 + A2:B2 + A2:Z + A1:B2:Z + A2:B2:Z


Y = -0.80420 + 1.55943*A2 + 1.55943*Z + 0.12481*A1:B2 - 0.09231*A2:B2 + 0.05906*A2:Z - 0.06872*A1:B2:Z + 0.01222*A2:B2:Z
```

Where `A1`,`A2`,`B1` and `B2` are variables that take 0 or 1 depending or the value for the specific observation. Replace all those variables by their proper value for what your are looking for and solve the equation. For the effect of B:

```
Y = -0.80420 + 1.55943*0 + 1.55943*Z + 0.12481*1*B2 - 0.09231*0*B2 + 0.05906*0*:Z - 0.06872*1*B2:Z + 0.01222*0*B2:Z 
Y = -0.80420 + 1.55943*Z + 0.12481*B2 + 0.06872*B2:Z
```

so if `B==B1`, then `B2==0`

```
Y = -0.80420 + 1.55943*Z + 0.12481*0 + 0.06872*0:Z
Y = -0.80420 + 1.55943*Z
```

so a increase of 1.55943 of Y with a increase of one Z

If if `B==B2`, then `B2==1`

```
Y = -0.80420 + 1.55943*Z + 0.12481*1 + 0.06872*1:Z
Y = 0.92901 + 1.62815*Z
```

so a increase of 1.62815 of Y with a increase of one Z

It is interpreted as : The effect of Z is more important when `B==B2`.

Note: Changing the order of you model shouldn't have any effect.